# HTACCESS force to have html extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I changed my CMS and now my URLs are without .html ending except index.html.

My current .htaccess

```
   RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ includes/sitemap.php?datei=$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^. index.php [L]
```

I am using this Code for .htaccess to remove .html

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://domain.com$1
```

**Edit**

My old URLs are like below which are as 404 Error listed

```
http://domain.com/motor/servo.html
http://domain.com/arduino.html
```

My new Systems SEO generates URL without .html extension and some Main Files has the .php extension.

What regex could I use to get it solved?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule with **negative lookahead regex**:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^((?!index)[^.]+)\.html$ http://domain.com/$1
```

**EDIT:** Based on your revised question you can have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!index)[^.]+)\.html$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ includes/sitemap.php?datei=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^. index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well this did not solve my Problem. Seems that index want to keep php instead .html extension. Dont know what I should use now.

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your revised question. Try it now.

Comment: One Problem which is not working. The result seems like that `http://domain.com/www/wordpress/arduino.html`. The root folder is added between the the Domain and .html.